# Plotting line graphs in matplotlib with correct dates

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, linegraph

I have been struggling with this for a few days and I feel like it's something really simple that I am missing. I thought I would reach out and hopefully someone can help me. All I am trying to do is plot a line graph from my dataset. I have tried many different methods but it keeps showing up with the same problem.

Here's my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('penalty_data_set_2.csv')
df['OFFENCE_MONTH'] = pd.to_datetime(df['OFFENCE_MONTH'])
print(df.head)


values = df.groupby('OFFENCE_MONTH')['TOTAL_NUMBER'].sum()


plt.plot(values.index,values)
```

here's what I get.

[Line graph plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIBkH.png)

and the dataframe [df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTVhh.png)

The dataset that I am using is from https://www.kaggle.com/llihan/australia-nsw-traffic-penalty-data-20112017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check if the date is parsed as YYYY-MM-DD instead of YYYY-DD-MM?

It looks like matplotlib is putting all values on the first days of each year, which would be the case if the date was parsed wrong confusing days and months.

Comment: I added this to my code `df = pd.read_csv('penalty_data_set_2.csv', parse_dates=['OFFENCE_MONTH'], dayfirst=True)` and it worked! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Glad it helped. Could you mark my answer as useful and/or solution? :)

Comment: Would love to but I don't have any reputation. :( This is my first post